# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF while parsing if statement in xml sitemap

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

i am trying to create xml sitemap i have a column album_image in my database. in start day's i did't upload album image and the column store '0' as value after years ago i start uploading album image. now i want to create sitemap for it. if album_image == 0 display static image else display album iamge. how can i use if statment in $xml .=

```
$xml .= '<image:image>';
        $xml .= '<image:loc>'.SITE_URL. if($row->album_image == '0'){'images/video_icon.png'}else{'media/'.$row->cat_id.'/images/'.$row->album_image.'}</image:loc>';
        $xml .= '<image:caption>'.$row->album_name.'</image:caption>';
        $xml .= '</image:image>';
```

i am getting this error " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in E:\wamp\www\site\sitemap-album.php on line 15 "

Comment: You can't put an if statement there. you need to separate it.

Comment: basically i am not coder can you explain how to do.

Comment: Probably the wrong website for you... but I've answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the if condition:

```
$xml .= '<image:image>';
$xml .= '<image:loc>'.SITE_URL;

if($row->album_image == '0') {
   $xml .= 'images/video_icon.png';
 } else {
   $xml .= 'media/'.$row->cat_id.'/images/'.$row->album_image;
 }

 $xml .= '</image:loc>';
 $xml .= '<image:caption>'.$row->album_name.'</image:caption>';
 $xml .= '</image:image>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user this also  $xml .= '';

```
 $xml .= '<image:loc>'.SITE_URL. ($row->album_image == '0')?'images/video_icon.png':'media/'.$row->cat_id.'/images/'.$row->album_image.'</image:loc>';
    $xml .= '<image:caption>'.$row->album_name.'</image:caption>';
    $xml .= '</image:image>';
```

Answer (score 0):

the full code is bellow . now i m geting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in"

```
$sql = "SELECT * from albums  LIMIT 0, 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
        $xml .= '<url>';
        $xml .= '<loc>'.SITE_URL.$row->album_url.'-album-1</loc>';
        $xml .= '</url>';
        $xml .= '<image:image>';
        $xml .= '<image:loc>'.SITE_URL;

        if($row->album_image == '0') {
           $xml . = 'images/video_icon.png';
         } else {
           $xml .= 'media/'.$row->cat_id.'/images/'.$row->album_image.';
         }

         $xml .= '</image:loc>';
         $xml .= '<image:caption>'.$row->album_name.'</image:caption>';
         $xml .= '</image:image>';
    }
}
$xml .= '</urlset>';
echo $xml;
```

Comment: I've fixed my code. Use that one instead. You shouldn't post an answer as an update.

Answer (score 0):

Every PHP statement must end with semi colon `(;)`.

It has an exception: Last statement in the file.

`echo` statement after some code needs that previous statement is closed.

Concatenation can work, but, for `echo`, closing previous statement is the only option.

Use ternary operator and store result in variable.

Use that variable to make code readable.

Complete code:

```
$videoImage = ($row->album_image == '0') ? 'images/video_icon.png' : 'media/'.$row->cat_id.'/images/'.$row->album_image;
$xml .= '<image:image>';
$xml .= '<image:loc>'.SITE_URL . $videoImage . '</image:loc>';
$xml .= '<image:caption>'.$row->album_name.'</image:caption>';
$xml .= '</image:image>';
```